# Bulk export mails and folders from RoundCube to Thunderbird

Tags: email, export, thunderbird, webmail, roundcube

i need to export all mails and folders from RoundCube to Thunderbird

What i tried so far?

- Skipped one by one, because i have cca 100.000 mails only in inbox
- Tried to transfer all emails and folders to new "Backup" folder then download it all and nothing
- Tried SysTools Maildir and nothing
- Googled for 48 hours and no valid solutions

If anyone had similar problem and solved it, please share it.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, i've found most simplest and stupidest solution. Connect with mail client and download mails from mail server to local folders, then export/import to client you use

Comment: How is that ? Can you describe the process please ? I am having same problem